# Change Label Value at runtime in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making a simple program in which user enters his username and then in next form, in label I want "Hello Username" where username is which entered in previous form. But I am not able to do it.
I tried this which shows above message but only when I hover mouse over it.

```
  lblUser.Text = "Hello " + user + "!"
  lblUser.Refresh()
```

So please guys, any suggestions!!

Comment: would `Me.Refresh()` not redraw the whole form? Maybe try that.

Comment: is that code in an event?

Comment: How you defined user. Since it is on another form create property for it.

Comment: Show the code how you call the second form and what happens in the Form constructor, Form_Load. From this code, it should work (even without the refresh)

Comment: winforms or webforms?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call a variable from another Form call the Form's Name before

```
 Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    lblUser.Text = "Hello " + Form1.user + "!"
    lblUser.Refresh()
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that in code page

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    lblUser.Text = "Hello " + user + "!"
          lblUser.Refresh()
 End Sub
```

Or double click in design mode and put your code there!